# If we had a complete metric space with no isolated points, then singular points are nowhere dense

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a complete metric space. I am trying ot prove whether or not each point in $x$ is nowhere dense if $X$ has no isolated points.

idea: the closure of a point is itself, and the interior of a point is empty, so the closure of the interior is empty which is what I take to mean nowhere dense - however I do not see where I use the fact that $X$ is complete, or that it has no isolated points.

If it did have an isolated point, then obviously I can draw a ball around that isolated point which means it is dense so I can see why no isolated points are needed, but I can't particular use them in my idea.

Additionally, why is $X$ being complete required?

Any way to progress would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify the question - "no-where dense" applies to sets, not points. Also, what is a 'singular' point - is this the same as an 'isolated' point?  Are you trying to say something like the space is no-where dense at every point, that is every open set around every x has an interior?

Comment: I mean the set of points $ \{ x \}$ for all x

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is an isolated point, i.e. there is $r>0$ such that
$d(x,y)\ge r $ for all $y\in X$ different from $x$, then the ball $B(x,r)=\lbrace y\in X: d(x,y)<r\rbrace =\lbrace x\rbrace$ is open.

Completeness is indeed not needed.

Comment: how does this prove that one set point $\{ x \}$ is nowhere dense?

Comment: No, this shows that $\lbrace x\rbrace$ is somewhere dense if $x$ is isolated. By definition, a set is somewhere dense if its closure contains interior points.

Comment: @Jochen - {0,1} is the set of two isolated points and is nowhere dense what we would expect.   You showed that there's an open set containing just {x} but the interior of the closure of this set would be empty.  Not proven.

Comment: You said that I showed that $\lbrace x\rbrace$ is open. Of course, $x$ is then an interior point of $\overline{\lbrace x\rbrace}$.